# How to use ortools to solve quadratic programming in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

For example, how can I simply find the minimum of (x-1)^2 via ortools in Python?

I read the document of ortools, but I cannot find it. I knew it does not belong to linear optimization, but I cannot find a proper type in its document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google OR-Tools does not support quadratic programming. [This page](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) contains a list of what it supports:

> Google Optimization Tools (OR-Tools) is a fast and portable software suite for solving combinatorial optimization problems. The suite contains:
>
> - A constraint programming solver.
> - A simple and unified interface to several linear programming and mixed integer programming solvers, including CBC, CLP, GLOP, GLPK, Gurobi, CPLEX, and SCIP.
> - Graph algorithms (shortest paths, min cost flow, max flow, linear sum assignment).
> - Algorithms for the Traveling Salesman Problem and Vehicle Routing Problem.
>   Bin packing and knapsack algorithms.

The following link clarifies that the mixed integer programming (MIP) support does not include quadratic MIP (MIQP):
https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/598

You might check out this resource for ideas of how to do QP in Python:
https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know I could use cvxopt or scipy.optimize for quadratic programming, but I just wanted to try ortools, and I cannot find the proper function.

Comment: @Kai: there is no proper function in ortools: it cannot do quadratic optimization.

Comment: there is a quadratic example here : https://github.com/ogunheper/google-or-tools-sample/blob/55bc62064db87e33194ce3cd200a0f3a5c15b1e9/src/test/java/com/ortools/OrToolsDemoApplicationTest.java#L237

Comment: It looks like ortools was updated to include this functionality after I wrote the answer, so my original response is no longer correct